# Sequelize belongToMany cascade delete

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js, sequelize-cli

Good day, everyone. I have two tables (Project, Configuration) that are connected as belongsToMany (ProjectConfigurations). I need to delete the project (Project) and, as a result, I need to delete Configurations that are connected with this project. How can I do it?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your need use onDelete: 'CASCADE' in **`'projects.model.js'`**:

```
const Projects = sequelize.define('projects', other_stuffs);
...
Projects.associate = function (models) {
  this.belongsToMany(models.get('configurations'), {
    through: 'project_configurations',
    foreignKey: 'project_id',
    onUpdate: 'CASCADE', // optional
    onDelete: 'CASCADE',
  });
  return this;
};
...
```

and in **`'configurations.model.js'`**:

```
const Configurations = sequelize.define('configurations', other_stuffs);
...
Configurations.associate = function (models) {
  this.belongsToMany(models.get('projects'), {
    through: 'project_configurations',
    foreignKey: 'configurations_id',
    onUpdate: 'CASCADE', // optional
    onDelete: 'CASCADE',
  });
  return this;
};
...
```